# How to use Authorize without ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

In My project use identity without Asp.net identity
I'm doing the login section and 
I want use [Authorize(Role="...")] But I do not know how to do it.

Please help me use it

StartUp.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5000);
            });
```

Login Action

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User();

                user = _iuser.LoginUser(login.Mobile, login.Password);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.IsActive)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>()
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.Id.ToString()),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Mobile)
                        };
                        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
                        {
                            IsPersistent = login.IsRemember
                        };

                        HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, properties);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Active));
                    }
```

user class:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Role Class:

```
public class Role
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

For Tips:
I'm using ASP.NET CORE 2.2 and Entity Frame Work Core 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Add `Role Claim` in the claims list

```cs
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
```

2. Create [custom authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: The code you have given `claims.Add...` is to be added to the Login controller?